# Disable c++ debugger in AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, android-studio-2.2, android-debug

Since AndroidStudio update 2.2, it takes a very long time for my native code app to start (I see a blank screen for ~20sec).

My guess is that it's because it takes a long time for the c++ debugger to settle.

Is its possible to disable it (and use only the good old java debugger)?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I just had the same problem. You can edit your "Run/Debug Configuration" for the project.  In the "Debugger" tab change "Debug type" from 'auto' to 'Java'. Solved it for me.

Comment: This option seems to be missing in Android Studio 2.3 :(

Comment: @ohaleck  The option is present in version 2.3.

Comment: Just to help some folks out, in Android Studio 2.3.3 you can find this option by selecting your Configurations (The Drop down right next the the Run button you click to run the app). Then selection Edit Configurations > Debugger > Debug Type

Comment: thanks, it was so annoying when it tried to copy some .so files to Android phone and other useless stuff for a very long time I just could not wait anymore...  ADB itself isn't that fast and this C++ debugger makes it more worse. Why it can't work fast as it works on iOS? on iOS with Xcode (macOS) it copies app to iPhone fast even over Wi-Fi

Answer (score 16):

[image]

You can select the "attach debugger to Android process icon", and choose the Java Debugger on the drop down list.